# How to destroy a class in C#

Tags: class, garbage-collection, dispose

i was trying to destroy a class when i want, but it just doesn't get destroyed.
I want to destroy it even if it had references in other places
and and turn those references into nulls.
Like in unity when you create a component and you destroy it and it gets destroyed.
And all references turn into nulls.

if there is a way please tell me, Thanks.

I tried IDispose but i don't know if it's wrong.
A reference to it should be null but its not.
I called the dispose function but a reference to it says its not null.

Comment: There is no way for doing this in .NET. The questions is - WHY you want to do it?

Comment: i want to make a class and have like classes witch execute code, like the components in unity.